I have a cluster patroni, patroni state show streaming, but HAProxy show DOWN, It's normal or not
List excute from patronictl -c /etc/patroni.yml list
result from excute
This is haproxy config
global
    maxconn 100

defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    retries 2
    timeout client 30m
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout server 30m
    timeout check 5s

listen stats
    mode http
    bind *:7000
    stats enable
    stats uri /

listen postgres
    bind *:5000
    option httpchk
    http-check expect status 200
    default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server node1 <ip-node1>:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008
    server node2 <ip-node2>:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008

And HA Proxy show
result haproxy show
Switch leader still work when i turn off one of 2 servers.
Know it's normal or something wrong
